# Resize background(img) without cropping it

Tags: css, image

I called a background image in css to make an image map. The way I've done so seems to have made difficult to resize without it cropping from the origin point. Here is my current css for calling the image.

```
ul#LittleItaly {
list-style: none;
background: url(images/Littleitaly_Map.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
height: 1600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

When I change the width or height it cuts off parts of the image. Similar to Photoshop changing canvas size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-size:cover

it should do the trick